# Student and Subjects in a query

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me how to possibly do this query:

I have 2 tables namely Students and Subjects, and what I want to do is get all the students with more than one subjects in the Subject table. Also I want to show the count of subjects that each student has.

Thanks you!

Comment: Then start coding! And if you run into problems: share your code and data. And, maybe, tell us which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Please explore your question with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: At least provide the schema, it looks like an N-to-N relation, so must be 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `join` between Students and Subjects tables ,and for count `aggregate` function , below query can be your solution

```
   select st.id,st.name,count(sb.subjectid) as numberofTakenSubject
   from Students st inner join Subjects sb 
   on st.id=sb.student_id
    group by st.id,st.name
    having count(*)>1
```

BTW your question should be more clear and specific like 
Students and Subject tables structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select studentid,count(subjectid)  from students inner join subjects 
on student.id=subjects.studentid
group by studentid
having count(subjectid)>1
```